# Weird error appearing randomly in terminal

Tags: command-line, acpi

I installed a few hours ago Ubuntu 14.04 and since I started using it I'm seeing a weird error always appearing in terminal :

```
[ 3099.912152] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires Package (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[ 3099.912316] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[ 3099.912343] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
```

This error appears randomly when I'm writing in the terminal (not when I confirm a command, only when I'm looking at a terminal and not necessarily logged). Note that it occurred one time in the graphic terminal but never occurred again. Since that time it always happened in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> terminal.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/842134/6969 (can unfortunately not close it yet, lacking votes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think It's just like a built in reminder letting you know that you ACPI is out of date.
If I am right then doing in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will fix your little issue.

Note: Doing the upgrade will take approx. 10-30 minutes depending on internet speed

Comment: Yea a common tip when installing any linux distro is to run the system's update and upgrade to ensure all packages and versions are up to date.
Be aware of your Distro's package manager aswell, not all use Aptitude, some use YUM.